# set ignore case value in when expression on strings

Tags: string, kotlin, contains, case-sensitive

I know how to check a string is in another string 
like this code.

```
when (myString) {
        in "FirstString"  -> {
                // some stuff
        }
        in "SecondString" -> {
                // some stuff
        }
        else -> {
                // some stuff
        }
}
```

`in` keyword under the hood calls this method `CharSequence.contains(other: CharSequence, ignoreCase: Boolean = false)`

**the question is this :**

is there any way that in this case i can set `ignoreCase = true` ?

Comment: an option is to do `when (myString.toLowerCase())` and have the cases in lowercase

Comment: @ShreyGarg. thanks for your response , it can help, but ignore case and toLowerCase() are not equal.

Comment: Not the same but IMHO toLowerCase should suffice in the given scenario. Do you think there is some case here which might fail when using toLowerCase?

Comment: no , but there is a point , if we want to choose this way, therefore for all branches of our `when` we should write `.toLowerCase()` like this , `"FirstString".toLowerCase()`  , `"SecondString".toLowerCase()`

Comment: Yes, if they're variable then this would be required. But if they're constants, simple "firststring", "secondstring" will do.

Comment: Yes , you are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare an ad-hoc local operator function `contains` for strings before `when`:

```
fun main() {

    operator fun String.contains(other: String): Boolean = this.contains(other, ignoreCase = true)

    when(myString) {
        in "firstString" -> ...
    }
}
```

This way that function will be invoked for `in` operator instead of the one declared in the standard library because it's located in the closer scope.

Note, however, that this trick works only if the original `contains` function is an extension. If it's a member function, it cannot be overridden with an extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [toLowerCase()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-lower-case.html) function here :

```
when (myString.toLowerCase()) {
    in "firststring"  -> {
            // some stuff
    }
    in "secondstring" -> {
            // some stuff
    }
    else -> {
            // some stuff
    }
}
```

For the cases of `when`, if they're **variables** `toLowerCase()` needs to be called on each of them. But, if they're **constants**, simple using lower case strings will work - `"firststring"`, `"secondstring"`